# Can I launch an Android app from incoming SMS/MMS messages?

Tags: android, sms, mms, self-extracting

I would like to know if I can launch a program via incoming MMS/SMS? More on the MMS side of things.

Workflow:

- MMS sent to Android device
- self executable MMS

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can create a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to listen for the android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED intent. In the receiver you can launch another activity to show the message or whatever. There is an example in the [sdk](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/SmsMessageReceiver.html) and you can also check out source to [SmsPopup](http://code.google.com/p/android-smspopup/).

Comment: @Robby Pond which sample in the sdk has the example?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know sms and mms are both handled in the same way.
How to use, see above